# Should I use cocos2D or andengine?

Tags: android, andengine, cocos2d-android

What is the project the more active/Stable?
Can you say me the deep diference between cocos2D and andengine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959337/cocos-vs-andengine-for-android/15900159#159001591

might be helpful to you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using AndEngine for one of my projects, and I must say, it's rather nice. A little comparision between LibGDX and AndEngine:

1) AndEngine

- Only for Android.
- High level, you propably won't need any direct calls for `GL` functions.
- Quite easy to learn, and to code with.
- There are versions (source) for OpenGL ES 1.0 / 1.1 / 2.0 (with support for shaders)

2) LibGDX

- Multiplatform (http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)
- You will be able test your code directly on PC
- Harder to learn

The question is, do you need the LibGDX platform freedom, or maybe you are making project only for Android?

Also, look at that nice list of Android engines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206089/game-engine-for-android).

Answer (score 5):

I would definitly choose Andengine. Cocos2D for Android is yet too buggy.

Answer (score 2):

AndEngine was specifically designed for coding-efficiency, libGDX gives you a little more freedom but requires a little more work. So LibGDX allows you to the low-level stuff easier, which is a little harder to do in AndEngine.

Answer (score 1):

I think cocos2d-android is not an active project like cocos2d-iphone and cocos2d-x .
It haven't been updated for quite a long time.