# Android 2D Game advice

Tags: android, 2d

Hi there I want to design 2D games for android but I don't know where to start. I haven't developed any software for android platform either. Should I first learn programming on Android platform or find a book about 2D game development for Android and start from there?

Thanks for your help
Much appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with programming on the Android platform. Continue with a game framework, there are many. But almost *all* of them are some packages with classes added on top of the Android classes - it's not a brand new framework. So you *must* be familiar with the regular Android platform.

For the game framework, there are a few I know, pick one:

- [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)
- [libGDX](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/)
- [cocos2d-android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/)

Personally, I know AndEngine and it is really good in my opinion. There were some discussions about these 3 frameworks on SO, here are some of them:

- [Should I use cocos2D or andengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952781/should-i-use-cocos2d-or-andengine)
- [Andengine vs libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669268/andengine-vs-libgdx)
- [What's the best free Android game engine? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994508/whats-the-best-free-android-game-engine)
- [Cocos2D OR libgdx for Android Game Developement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552176/cocos2d-or-libgdx-for-android-game-developement) (AndEngine is mentioned here too).

Comment: Thank you very much. I might ask you more questions later on if you don't mind. Cheers